# Ruby on Rails rjust Not Returning Expected Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using `rjust` in a helper function as follows:

```
def get_child_id(service_name, child_id)
  ..
  return 'FL' + child_id.to_s.rjust(6, "0");
end
```

The function is being called like so:

```
<%= get_child_id(@ticket.service_type, @ticket.service_id) %>
```

and returns `FL123456` (`123456` being the database value) whereas I would expect `FL000000123456`

The `service_id` is an `INT` column in the database.

I use `rjust` in my models in the exact same way and it works fine so I'm at a loss why it's not working here, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `12` instead:

```
def get_child_id(service_name, child_id)
  # ...
  return 'FL' + child_id.to_s.rjust(12, "0");
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try this out

from ruby doc:-

```
 rjust(integer, padstr=' ') → new_str
```

> If integer is greater than the length of str, returns a new String of
>   length integer with str right justified and padded with padstr;
>   otherwise, returns str.

```
"hello".rjust(4)            #=> "hello"
"hello".rjust(20)           #=> "               hello"
"hello".rjust(20, '1234')   #=> "123412341234123hello"
```

it means you want a padding of more than 6 in your case 12.